# Why is my directive not being picked up inside shared module in Angular?

Tags: angular

So I have been struggling for a while with this problem and have not been able to find a solution to it. No searches seem to turn up a solution close to my problem..

In my application I have a `Shared Module` that is being imported into my `App Module` under the `imports` array.

Under my `Shared Module` I have my custom directive which is under the `declarations` array as well as being exported in the `exports` array.

In my solution I have a module that I would like to share from my `Shared Module` so that it can be accessed anywhere in my app.

It is in the `imports` array of my `Shared Module` as well as in the `imports` array.

My directive has two input values in it namely:

```js
@Input() input1: string;
@Input() input2: string;
```

Inside the module that is imported to the `Shared Module` there is a component where I would like to use the directive.

Inside the component template I have the directive with the values linked to the inputs but I keep getting the error: `Can't bind to 'input1' since it isn't a known property of 'div'` for instance.

I have set up a StackBlitz to illustrate with a fake directive that may help with illustrating my point: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vhevr. It does not use an input but illustrates the file layout.

**UPDATE 1**

I did manage to find a work around in shared module instead of importing and exporting the Module where those components are found I just added all the components to the declarations array and exports array of `SharedModule` and it seems to work now? Not sure if there is a better solution however.

Answer (score 0):

import SubNavigationPanelModule in AppModule, remove it from SharedModule and then import SharedModule in SubNavigationPanelModule.

Comment: This did not work as it started to complain about inputs on my component inside `SubNavigationPanelModule` not being found. About to edit my post with a possible solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things,

1) Setting background color for text won't work it should be color.
2) Since you have exported highlight directive from shared module and imported the same app module, we can use it in elements from app module some thing like,

```
<hello appHighlight name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p appHighlight>
   Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<sub-navigation-panel appHighlight></sub-navigation-panel>
```